# How does BreezeJS handle deadlocking situations?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, breeze

So the question is mostly in the title but after some research I can't really find any deeper information about this.  Mostly I want to know if a deadlock situation occurs does Breeze automatically reattempt the commit or does it just return an error back to the front end to try saving again?  Any documentation or articles going deeper into this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To a certain extent this depends on the server backend that you are using. But in general breeze will NOT attempt to retry a deadlock failure and will instead return an exception indicating that a deadlock occurred.  You can then retry the save yourself by handling the client side exception and reexecuting the query.

Note that because of the way that most breeze servers automatically *toposort* the entities in a save request, deadlocks are much less likely than if such a sort was not performed. The idea here is that by ensuring that multiple instances of a program use the same ordering when updating the same set of tables, we reduce the possibility of a deadlock.

This toposorting is part of any Entity Framework based backend as well as the Breeze Node/Sequelize (MySQL, Postgress) provider, and is likely to be added to the Breeze NHibernate and MongoDb providers in the near future.